# Sort items in a nested hash by their values

Tags: ruby, sorting

I'm being sent a nested hash that needs to be sorted by its values. For example:

```
@foo = {"a"=>{"z"=>5, "y"=>3, "x"=>88}, "b"=>{"a"=>2, "d"=>-5}}
```

When running the following:

```
@foo["a"].sort{|a,b| a[1]<=>b[1]}
```

I get:

```
[["y", 3], ["z", 5], ["x", 88]]
```

This is great, it's exactly what I want. The problem is I'm not always going to know what all the keys are that are being sent to me so I need some sort of loop. I tried to do the following:

```
@foo.each do |e|   
  e.sort{|a,b| a[1]<=>b[1]}
end
```

This to me makes sense since if I manually call @foo.first[0] I get

```
"a"
```

and @foo.first[1] returns

```
{"z"=>5, "y"=>3, "x"=>8}
```

but for some reason this isn't sorting properly (e.g. at all). I assume this is because the each is calling sort on the entire hash object rather than on "a"'s values. How do I access the values of the nested hash without knowing what it's key is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to loop over the hash like this:

```
@foo.each do |key, value|
  @foo[key] = value.sort{ |a,b| a[1]<=>b[1] }
end
```

Comment: 1) it's conceptually preferrable to use Enumerable#sort_by instead of sort, check Phrogz's answer. 2) this makes an inplace operation, creating new objects (functional approach) makes the code easier to follow.

Comment: @tokland - all great points, but my goal was to follow the OPs code while still solving the actual problem. While creating new objects might be easier to follow, it's cleaner imo to not create a temporary variable if you are going to assign it back to the original anyways.

Answer (score 4):

```
@foo = {"a"=>{"z"=>5, "y"=>3, "x"=>88}, "b"=>{"a"=>2, "d"=>-5}}
@bar = Hash[ @foo.map{ |key,values| [ key, values.sort_by(&:last) ] } ]
```

Or, via a less-tricky path:

```
@bar = {}
@foo.each do |key,values|
  @bar[key] = values.sort_by{ |key,value| value }
end
```

In both cases `@bar` turns out to be:

```
p @bar
#=> {
#=>   "a"=>[["y", 3], ["z", 5], ["x", 88]],
#=>   "b"=>[["d", -5], ["a", 2]]
#=> }
```

Comment: +1 but, I'd write an explicit getter for the sort_by: values.sort_by { |k, v| v }. Will we see the day that Ruby ships the absolutely necessary Enumerable#to_hash? I'm tired of recommending Facet's Enumberable#mash for something that should be built-in, sigh... @bar = @foo.to_hash { |key, values| [key, values.sort_by { |k, v| v }] }

Answer (score 1):

My coworker came up with a slightly more flexible solution that will recursively sort an array of any depth:

```
def deep_sort_by(&block)
  Hash[self.map do |key, value|
    [if key.respond_to? :deep_sort_by
      key.deep_sort_by(&block)
    else
      key
    end,

    if value.respond_to? :deep_sort_by
      value.deep_sort_by(&block)
    else
      value
    end]

  end.sort_by(&block)]
end
```

You can inject it into all hashes and then just call it like this:

```
myMap.deep_sort_by { |obj| obj }
```

The code would be similar for an array. We [published it as a gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/deepsort) for others to use, see [blog post](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/08/31/deeply-sort-nested-ruby-arrays-and-hashes/) for additional details.

Disclaimer: I work for this company.

Answer (score 0):

in your example `e` is an temporary array containing a [key,value] pair. In this case, the  character key and the nested hash.  So `e.sort{|a,b|...}` is going to try to compare the character to the hash, and fails with a runtime error.   I think you probably meant to type `e[1].sort{...}`.   But even that is not going to work correctly, because you don't store the sorted hash anywhere:  `@foo.each` returns the original @foo and leaves it unchanged.

The better solution is the one suggested by @Pan Thomakos:

```
@foo.each do |key, value|
  @foo[key] = value.sort{ |a,b| a[1]<=>b[1] }
end
```